# How can I disable this warrning in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

Does anyone know how can I disable this error in Visual studio?
[image]

Im not sure if this warrning is from visual studio or from some extension

Comment: Have you actually searched for the warning in google/msdn?